# Passing the PTX program to the CUDA driver directly

Tags: c, cuda, ptx

The CUDA driver API provides loading the file containing PTX code from the filesystem. One usually does the following:

```
CUmodule module;
CUfunction function;

const char* module_file = "my_prg.ptx";
const char* kernel_name = "vector_add";

err = cuModuleLoad(&module, module_file);
err = cuModuleGetFunction(&function, module, kernel_name);
```

In case one generates the PTX files during runtime (on the fly) going through file IO seems to be a waste (since the driver has to load it back in again).

Is there a way to pass the PTX program to the CUDA driver directly (e.g. as a C string) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from the `ptxjit` CUDA example:

Define the PTX program as a C string as

```
char myPtx32[] = "\n\
    .version 1.4\n\
    .target sm_10, map_f64_to_f32\n\
    .entry _Z8myKernelPi (\n\.param .u32 __cudaparm__Z8myKernelPi_data)\n\
    {\n\
    .reg .u16 %rh<4>;\n\
    .reg .u32 %r<8>;\n\

    // Other stuff

    .loc    28      18      0\n\
    exit;\n\
    }\n\
 ";
```

then

```
 cuModuleLoadDataEx(phModule, myPtx32, 0, 0, 0);
```

and finally

```
 cuModuleLoadDataEx(phModule, myPtx, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cuModuleLoadDataEx](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html#group__CUDA__MODULE_1g9e8047e9dbf725f0cd7cafd18bfd4d12) function to load PTX source from a NULL-terminated string.